# Matrix Multiplication in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have encountered an issue with my project which is to do with matrix multiplication. I have to multiply two matrices together, one which I have made and one that is a parameter. However,it has to pass a jasmine test and currently it does not pass due to an NaN error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
My matrix code:

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {
    this.Matrix = [
      [pX0, pX1, pX2],
      [pY0, pY1, pY2],
      [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];
  }
  getX0() {
    return this.mX0;
  }
  setX0(pX0) {
    this.mX0 = pX0;
  }
  getX1() {
    return this.mX1;
  }
  setX1(pX1) {
    this.mX1 = pX1;
  }
  getX2() {
    return this.mX2;
  }
  setX2(pX2) {
    this.mX2 = pX2;
  }
  getY0() {
    return this.mY0;
  }
  setY0(pY0) {
    this.mY0 = pY0;
  }
  getY1() {
    return this.mY1;
  }
  setY1(pY1) {
    this.mY1 = pY1;
  }
  getY2() {
    return this.mY2;
  }
  setY2(pY2) {
    this.mY2 = pY2;
  }
  getZ0() {
    return this.mZ0;
  }
  setZ0(pZ0) {
    this.mZ0 = pZ0;
  }
  getZ1() {
    return this.mZ1;
  }
  setZ1(pZ1) {
    this.mZ1 = pZ1;
  }
  getZ2() {
    return this.mZ2;
  }
  setZ2(pZ2) {
    this.mZ2 = pZ2;
  }
  getElement(pRow, pColumn) {
    return this.Matrix[pRow][pColumn];
  }
  static createIdentity() {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  static createTranslation(pTranslationVector) {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, pTranslationVector.getX(), 0, 1, pTranslationVector.getY(), 0, 0, 1);
  }
  static createScale(pScaleVector) {
    return new Matrix(pScaleVector.getX(), 0, 0, 0, pScaleVector.getY(), 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  static createRotation(pRotationScalar) {
    return new Matrix(Math.cos(pRotationScalar), -Math.sin(pRotationScalar), 0, Math.sin(pRotationScalar), Math.cos(pRotationScalar), 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  multiply(pMatrix) {
    return new Matrix(this.getX0 * pMatrix.getX0, this.getX1 * pMatrix.getY0, this.getX2 * pMatrix.getZ0, this.getY0 * pMatrix.getX1, this.getY1 * pMatrix.getY1, this.getY2 * pMatrix.getZ1, this.getZ0 * pMatrix.getX2, this.getZ1 * pMatrix.getY2, this.getZ2 * pMatrix.getZ2);
  }
```

The test it has to pass:

```
describe("Multiply", function() {
var rotation, scaleVector, translationVector, translationMatrix,
  scaleMatrix, rotationMatrix, scaleXTranslationMatrix, translationXScaleMatrix,
  chainedMatrix;
rotation = Math.PI / 2;
rotationMatrix = Matrix.createRotation(rotation);
scaleVector = new Vector(2, 2, 1);
scaleMatrix = Matrix.createScale(scaleVector);
translationVector = new Vector(10, 20, 1);
translationMatrix = Matrix.createTranslation(translationVector);

describe("Scale X Translate", function() {
  scaleXTranslationMatrix = scaleMatrix.multiply(translationMatrix);
  it("Element (0,0) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(0, 0)).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("Element (0,1) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(0, 1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (0,2) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(0, 2)).toEqual(20);
  });

  it("Element (1,0) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(1, 0)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (1,1) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(1, 1)).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("Element (1,2) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(1, 2)).toEqual(40);
  });

  it("Element (2,0) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(2, 0)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,1) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(2, 1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,2) Set", function() {
    expect(scaleXTranslationMatrix.getElement(2, 2)).toEqual(1);
  });
});

describe("Translate X Scale", function() {
  translationXScaleMatrix = translationMatrix.multiply(scaleMatrix);
  it("Element (0,0) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(0, 0)).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("Element (0,1) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(0, 1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (0,2) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(0, 2)).toEqual(10);
  });

  it("Element (1,0) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(1, 0)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (1,1) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(1, 1)).toEqual(2);
  });

  it("Element (1,2) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(1, 2)).toEqual(20);
  });

  it("Element (2,0) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(2, 0)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,1) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(2, 1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,2) Set", function() {
    expect(translationXScaleMatrix.getElement(2, 2)).toEqual(1);
  });
});

describe("Chaining", function() {
  var cosAngle, sinAngle;
  cosAngle = Math.cos(Math.PI / 2);
  sinAngle = Math.sin(Math.PI / 2);
  chainedMatrix =
    translationMatrix.multiply(scaleMatrix).multiply(rotationMatrix);
  it("Element (0,0) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(0, 0)).toEqual(2 * cosAngle);
  });

  it("Element (0,1) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(0, 1)).toEqual(2 * -sinAngle);
  });

  it("Element (0,2) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(0, 2)).toEqual(10);
  });

  it("Element (1,0) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(1, 0)).toEqual(2 * sinAngle);
  });

  it("Element (1,1) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(1, 1)).toEqual(2 * cosAngle);
  });

  it("Element (1,2) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(1, 2)).toEqual(20);
  });

  it("Element (2,0) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(2, 0)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,1) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(2, 1)).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Element (2,2) Set", function() {
    expect(chainedMatrix.getElement(2, 2)).toEqual(1);
  });
});

});

});
```

I'm out of ideas so any form of help would be great, thanks.

Comment: It might be beneficial to include *where* you're getting the error instead of making people make this runnable and figure it out. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, the error occurs when multiplying the two matrices together as rather than resulting in a integer, it results in a NaN error.

Comment: That is not specific enough. You're essentially making people run your code in order to understand what the issue is--that's a lot to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `multiply` method tries to multiply functions, not numbers:

```
multiply(pMatrix) {
  return new Matrix(
    this.getX0 * pMatrix.getX0,
    this.getX1 * pMatrix.getY0,
    this.getX2 * pMatrix.getZ0,
    this.getY0 * pMatrix.getX1,
    this.getY1 * pMatrix.getY1,
    this.getY2 * pMatrix.getZ1,
    this.getZ0 * pMatrix.getX2,
    this.getZ1 * pMatrix.getY2,
    this.getZ2 * pMatrix.getZ2
  );
}
```

That's the reason why you get `NaN` as a result. Either change the code to multiply the numeric values or call the getter functions:

```
multiply(pMatrix) {
  return new Matrix(
    this.getX0() * pMatrix.getX0(),
    this.getX1() * pMatrix.getY0(),
    this.getX2() * pMatrix.getZ0(),
    this.getY0() * pMatrix.getX1(),
    this.getY1() * pMatrix.getY1(),
    this.getY2() * pMatrix.getZ1(),
    this.getZ0() * pMatrix.getX2(),
    this.getZ1() * pMatrix.getY2(),
    this.getZ2() * pMatrix.getZ2()
  );
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

You also have update those getter functions as well, because they try to grab properties which aren't defined. For example, `getX0()` returns `this.mX0` internally. But `this.mX0` is never set and therefor returns `undefined`.

Change your getter functions like so:

```
...
getX0: function () {
  return this.getElement(0, 0);
}
...
```

You have to do this *for each getter*. The other solution would be to call the corresponding setter functions inside the constructor:

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {
    this.Matrix = [
      [pX0, pX1, pX2],
      [pY0, pY1, pY2],
      [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];

    this.setX0(pX0);
    this.setX1(pX1);
    // ...
    this.setZ2(pZ2);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Here is a "fixed" version of your `Matrix` class:

```js
class Matrix {
  constructor(pX0, pX1, pX2, pY0, pY1, pY2, pZ0, pZ1, pZ2) {
    this.__matrix = [
      [pX0, pX1, pX2],
      [pY0, pY1, pY2],
      [pZ0, pZ1, pZ2]
    ];
  }
  getX0() {
    return this.getElement(0, 0);
  }
  setX0(pX0) {
    return this.setElement(0, 0, pX0);
  }
  getX1() {
    return this.getElement(0, 1);
  }
  setX1(pX1) {
    return this.setElement(0, 1, pX1);
  }
  getX2() {
    return this.getElement(0, 2);
  }
  setX2(pX2) {
    return this.setElement(0, 2, pX2);
  }
  getY0() {
    return this.getElement(1, 0);
  }
  setY0(pY0) {
    return this.setElement(1, 0, pY0);
  }
  getY1() {
    return this.getElement(1, 1);
  }
  setY1(pY1) {
    return this.setElement(1, 1, pY1);
  }
  getY2() {
    return this.getElement(1, 2);
  }
  setY2(pY2) {
    return this.setElement(1, 2, pY2);
  }
  getZ0() {
    return this.getElement(2, 0);
  }
  setZ0(pZ0) {
    return this.setElement(2, 0, pZ0);
  }
  getZ1() {
    return this.getElement(2, 1);
  }
  setZ1(pZ1) {
    return this.setElement(2, 1, pZ1);
  }
  getZ2() {
    return this.getElement(2, 2);
  }
  setZ2(pZ2) {
    return this.setElement(2, 2, pZ2);
  }
  getElement(pRow, pColumn) {
    return this.__matrix[pRow][pColumn];
  }
  setElement(pRow, pColumn, value) {
    this.__matrix[pRow][pColumn] = value;
    return this;
  }
  toString() {
    return `Matrix([${this.__matrix.reduce((acc, row) => acc + '[' + row.join(',') + ']', '')}])`;
  }
  static createIdentity() {
    return new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  static isIdentity(pMatrix) {
    return Matrix.prototype.isPrototypeOf(pMatrix) &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[0][0] === 1 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[0][1] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[0][2] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[1][0] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[1][1] === 1 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[1][2] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[2][0] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[2][1] === 0 &&
           pMatrix.__matrix[2][2] === 1;
  }
  static createTranslation(pTranslationVector) {
    return new Matrix(
      1,
      0,
      pTranslationVector.getX(),
      0,
      1,
      pTranslationVector.getY(),
      0,
      0,
      1
    );
  }
  static createScale(pScaleVector) {
    return new Matrix(
      pScaleVector.getX(),
      0,
      0,
      0,
      pScaleVector.getY(),
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1
    );
  }
  static createRotation(pRotationScalar) {
    return new Matrix(
      Math.cos(pRotationScalar),
      -Math.sin(pRotationScalar),
      0,
      Math.sin(pRotationScalar),
      Math.cos(pRotationScalar),
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1
    );
  }
  multiply(pMatrix) {
    return new Matrix(
      this.getX0() * pMatrix.getX0(),
      this.getX1() * pMatrix.getY0(),
      this.getX2() * pMatrix.getZ0(),
      this.getY0() * pMatrix.getX1(),
      this.getY1() * pMatrix.getY1(),
      this.getY2() * pMatrix.getZ1(),
      this.getZ0() * pMatrix.getX2(),
      this.getZ1() * pMatrix.getY2(),
      this.getZ2() * pMatrix.getZ2()
    );
  }
}



// TEST
let m1 = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
let m2 = Matrix.createIdentity();

let m3 = m1.multiply(m2); // should give us identity again

console.log(Matrix.isIdentity(m3)); // should log true
console.log(m3.toString());
```

Comment: Tried the second bit of code you presented, still getting NaN error, cheers for the help any way

Comment: @david Updated my answer with a working implementation

Comment: Thanks so much, you been immensely helpful.